# Sonar gives circular dependency bug while using child layouts with RouterLink in Vaadin 14

Tags: vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I have a MainLayout and some other routes which are child of MainLayout. I have a drawer in MainLayout which has RouterLinks to those child routes. Now the issue is I have to mention class names of child layouts while creating the RouterLinks in MainLayout. And I have to mention MainLayout.class as layout parameter in Route annotation in child view classes. So it is causing circular dependency.
Is there any way to remove this circular dependency?

I didn't try anything to remove this bug because what I did was according to official docs, So I think I should ignore the issue but If there is any way to remove this bug then please share it.

Comment: I fixed it by [registering routes dynamically](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/routing/dynamic#getting-registered-routes-and-listening-for-changes)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.